# Prevent one module from installing as dev-master

Tags: version-control, composer-php

I have set my minimum stability to be dev but I'd like one module to avoid installing the dev-master release. I'd like to put in, for example, >=1.3 and not get dev-master. Is this possible?

Comment: Please share your `composer.json`.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research and changing how I searched I found that Composer has a prefer-stable option that can be used to achieve this